# mongoDB mongoose aggregation group array returns [object] Error

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Actually I want to aggregate based on username and contain place information.
It is working fine with the mongo shell

```
db.demo_datas.aggregate([{"$group":{"_id":"$user_screenname", "place":{"$push":{"place":"$user_geo"}}}}]);

{
"_id" : "orena001",
"place" : [
    {
        "place" : [
            11.158983,
            78.163335
        ]
    },
    {
        "place" : [
            11.137964,
            78.16126
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Now, when i used with node.js mongoose the place array is not returning the values. The mongoose node.js query is

```
   demodatas.aggregate([{$group:{"_id":"$user_screenname", "place":{"$push":{"place":"$user_geo"}}}}], function(err, data){

console.log(data);
});
```

but it returns result like this.

```
{ _id: 'orena001',
    place: 
     [ [Object],
       [Object] 
     ]
}
```

could any one help me to resolve this issues. Thanks advance.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following:

```
> console.log({ foo : { bar : [ { xxx : 1 } ] } })
{ foo: { bar: [ [Object] ] } }
```

This is showing similar output to what you are seeing. The reason for the unexpected output is that a regular `console.log()` will only show nested objects up to a specific depth, after which it will abbreviate the output (in this case, it will show `[Object]` instead of the actual object). This doesn't mean the object is invalid, though, it's just shown in this shorter format when you print it.

One solution to get to see the whole object is to convert it to JSON first:

```
> console.log('%j', { foo : { bar : [ { xxx : 1 } ] } })
{"foo":{"bar":[{"xxx":1}]}}
```

Or, in your case:

```
console.log('%j', data);
```

Comment: Hello @robertklep Thanks a lot.. It works great..nearly I wasted one night to resolve it .. Thanks again.. Have a great Day..